# Codeigniter best practice model

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, model

What is best practice model for method GetAll()?
I have problem when i can add parametr: where, group, where group itd.

my propositions:

1) 
Model:

```
public function GetAll()
{
    $this->db->select('articles.*');
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->join('admins', 'admins.id=articles.admin_id');
    $this->db->where('active', 1)

    return $this->db;
}
```

Controller:

```
$articles = $this
    ->articles_m
    ->GetAll()
    ->where('id', 2)
    ->get()
    ->result()
;
```

2) Classic
model:

```
public function GetAll($params = array())
{
    $this->db->select('articles.*');
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->join('admins', 'admins.id=articles.admin_id');
    $this->db->where('active', 1)

    if (array_key_exists('where', $params)) {
        $this->db->where($params['where']);
    }

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Controller:

```
$articles = $this
     ->articles_m
     ->GetAll(['where' => ['id' => 2]])
     ->result()
;
```

What is better?

option 1 is very elastic. I can use all method active records. But option 2 i must definet where/order_by etc. Group is when i can grouping "where".

Answer (score 0):

```
public function GetAll($id='', $search='', $limit='', $order='')
{
    $this->db->select('A.*');
    $this->db->from('articles as A');
    $this->db->join('admins as B', 'B.id=A.admin_id');
    $this->db->where('A.active', '1');
    if($id != ''){
    $this->db->where('A.id', $id);
    } 
    ...... etc
    return $this->db;
}
```

you can mix, add array support etc